# How to stop executing all tasks for 3 minutes and then continue executing code

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am having tasks which are running Work method

```
private void Work(Crawler crawler, PropertyBag propertyBag) {}
```

Now I want to stop all taks for 3 minutes and then continue with execution. I try with

`Thread.Sleep` but not working. Tasks still working. What is good solution to stop tasks for 3 minutes and then continue. Maybe locking and how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` does not work because it sleeps the current thread.

If you create the threads by hand, not using TPL, then you hopefully have a list/array of the threads.  You can use the Thread.Suspend and Thread.Resume methods.

```
foreach (var t in threads) t.Suspend();

// Then in 3 minutes.
foreach (var t in threads) t.Resume();
```

Note that Sleep/Resume are obsolete!

**EDIT**

Without having a list of threads, then you can use a `ManualResetEvent`.  In your Work method do a `.WaitOne()` on it before attempting to any work.

On your main thread call `.Reset` when you want to sleep the tasks, and then in 3 minutes call `.Set`.

Comment: what if everything is in Work method. Can I use ManualResetEvent and .Reset too in the same method?

Comment: becouse I make: ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
then mre.WaitOne(); and mre.Reset(); Thread.Sleep(3 * 60 * 1000); mre.Set(); but application still executing codes. Tasks are still working...

Comment: `mre.WaitOne()` should be inside your tasks.

Comment: @AgentFire is correct.  The mre should be either a member of all your tasks, not created per class or a static member of some class that workers can access.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Maybe you can post your final code to help others.

Comment: Your answer has been very helpful. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to automagically pause and resume tasks at will. However, you can place special "watchers" in the code you may want to have paused, like `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()` statements and reset them from another threads at any time.

Comment: That is what I would do, yes.